# BUILT IN ID for the android listView @android:id/list,CREATING AMBIGUITY

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have two fragments for the android layout of my application for the tablet  and,both of them having `Listview`.I am using the built in id  `android:id="@android:id/list"` for both of them.Now when I am trying to take their reference in my activity java file, I am confused that how will I do that.

---

**IMPORTANT POINT:**  I am taking there references in my activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);  
    notificationListView2=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);    //from first fragment
    notificationListView=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);//from second fragment
```

[image]

---

**IMPORTANT POINT:**  I am taking there references in my activity

Answer (score 1):

For `Fragments`, onCreateView is the method where your layout will be inflated.
This inflater returns a `View` object so call `findViewById(android.R.id.list)` on this view object.

eg.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_xml, container, false);
    rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    .....
    .... any other code ....
    .....
    return rootView;
}
```

This will ensure that the correct listview is being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

In each fragment you add will call to `onCreateView` method, in the given method, you have the possibility to take a reference to any object in your fragment, that is when you need to store the reference to your `ListView` items.

If you need somehow from your activity to access your `ListView` items, create methods to retreive the variables you have assigned in your `onCreateView` methods.

So in each fragment you will be able to do the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Right", "onCreateView()");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right, container, false);
    ListView lv_fragmentXXX = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list); //Where xxx is an identifier for each listview in each fragment
}
```

Comment: I am taking there references in my activity

Comment: Then create a method in your fragments to retreive each ListView, from each fragment, if it is not clear, add some code to clarify your question